# Vim E474: Invalid argument: backupcopy=

Tags: vim

Im getting this error when I re-open a given file. It gives a line number in that file, but it is different text that is on that line. So I can't establish a certain line or text that trigger this error.

My vimrc: http://pastebin.com/6YPVwePV

Comment: Are you using a session to re-open the file? There was a recently introduced bug that caused that in session files. Or maybe you have a modeline in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug on some versions of vim, which was fixed in 7.4.462. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/3u0PKRJrSjU/48W88Q6mLJ4J

and the thread that lead to that patch: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/x3t4oemwkXc/9HyfuEy7LV4J